# SqlDataReader for numeric data type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview, sqldatareader

I have this code:

```
public void nactiData()
{
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+nc_zajezd_vyber, con); 
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            zpocdnu.Text = reader.GetInt32(31).ToString();
            zcena3.Text = reader.GetDecimal(6).ToString();
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Problem is that it doesn't read `zcena3` because the datatype in the table is `numeric`.

On Microsoft's website is written that I should read it with `GetDecimal`, but it doesn't work either.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Using `*` with column positions is asking for trouble.  Write out the column names, like `GetString("col1")`

Comment: I tried that, what should replace *?

Comment: What **exact** datatype are those columns in SQL Server? If they are `int`, `smallint` or `bigint`; you need to use `.GetInt16/.GetInt32/.GetInt64` (not `.GetDecimal`). You said using `GetDecimal` *doesn't work* - ***how*** does it not work? Do you get an error? If so: ***what error*** ?

Comment: Oh, GetDecimal did work, I had nulls allowed. Thanks

Comment: @Andomar: it should be `reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("col1"))` (and typically the result of calling `GetOrdinal` would be executed only once and then cached in a variable).

Comment: "typically the result of calling GetOrdinal would be executed only once and then cached" - this caching will make a noticeable difference only if you have a large number of rows.  One way to do it is to wrap your reader in a System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator, which caches the ordinals for you.

Comment: @Joe: Agreed. (Didn't know about `DbEnumerator`, either. Unfortunate that the MSDN documentation is so vague about its intended usage.) Anyway: While caching indices might not improve performance for smaller result sets, it also shouldn't degrade it. So you tend to be on the safe side of things by just doing it, *if* you're willing to make the additional effort of declaring a few local variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You've solved your problem yourself, but let me suggest the following.)

Since you are dealing with a SQL Server data reader, use [**`GetSqlDecimal`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqldecimal.aspx) instead of `GetDecimal`:

- It should perform a little better (since it doesn't do any unnecessary conversion).
- It can also deal with `NULL` (via the `IsNull` property of the returned [`SqlDecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.aspx) value).